# When does C decide if char[] is a character array or a string?

Tags: c, variables

char[i] stands for declaration of a variable both a char array and a string. I know that C adds a null character to the end of the array if it is a string. However, how does C know when to add the null character, in other words, in what stage?

Comment: An array of char becomes a string when someone or something adds a null byte.  If you use initialization, the compiler adds the null byte.  If you use `strcpy()`, the function adds the null byte.  If you use `strncpy()`, the function might or might not add a null byte, and the result might or might not be a string — it depends.

Comment: C doesn't add a null character to the end of an array.

Comment: C only adds a null character at the end of *a string literal*, this makes `"Hellow world\n"`  to be the character sequence `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\n', '\0'}` but nothing else. String manipulation functions assume (some of them, e.g. `strlen(3)`) that the string is null terminated, but this is library implementation convention, and not language definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't,  C "strings" are just an assumption about arrays  ( that they have a 0 somewhere indicating the end of the string)

There is no type "string" in C, just libraries which deal with char arrays with the above assumption.  It is completely up to the library functions to manage the arrays and work out when to terminate them if needed.  Quite often these functions don't respect what memory was actually allocated for the array, it will assume there's enough allocated space for whatever it's doing

It would be entirely possible to use pascal type strings in C and write a string library using that convention if one wished.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't know the difference between a `char[]` or `char*` which is a string and a `char[]` or `char*` which isn't a string.

The only place where C will add a nul terminator is when you use a string literal.

```
const char x[] = "Hello, world!";
//                             ^ plus terminator, sizeof=14
const char *y = "Hello, world!";
//                            ^ plus terminator
```

You can just as easily create an array without a terminator:

```
const char x[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',',
                  ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'};
//                                                 ^ NO terminator
//                                                 sizeof=13
```

Okay, maybe not "just as easily", it's a fair bit of extra typing.  But you can see the point: it's the fact that you used double quotes `"..."` that added the nul terminator.

Certain library functions will also give you nul terminators, like `strcpy` or `snprintf`.